# Windows 8 Store MonoGame - How to extract bitmap from Camera

Tags: windows-8, camera, monogame

I am creating windows 8 store application with MonoGame framework. I want to get each bitmap from camera in order to process some image recognition on that bitmap. The thing is I only get the whole video stream from camera `(randomAccessStream)` but not each frame from the video.

```
 async private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //1. Initialize:
            mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
            randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

            await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();

            //2. create profile
            MediaEncodingProfile encordingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

            //3. start recording
            await mediaCaptureMgr.StartRecordToStreamAsync(encordingProfile, randomAccessStream);
        }
```

How can I receive new up-coming frame/bitmap from camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-capture-sample-adf87622)

It is a sample app from Microsoft. Among other things it shows:

- **How to capture an image** using the new LowLagPhotoCapture and LowLagPhotoControl classes.
- **How to capture a sequence of photos** using the new LowLagPhotoSequenceCapture and LowLagPhotoSequenceControl classes.
- ...

If you are going to process the images, you could just take pictures on an interval. I don't think you need to process every single frame of a video stream..